# How to create factories with attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

How to deal with factories and `attr_accessible`?

My example:

```
# model
class SomeModel

  attr_accessible :name, full_name, other_name

end

#spec
require 'spec_helper'

describe "test" do
  it do
    create(:some_model, name: "test name", user: User.first) #factory
  end

end

#error
ruby(17122,0x12a055000) malloc: *** error for object 0x8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I think the error is because `user_id` is not in `attr_accessible` attributes.

Comment: If that was the problem active record would raise an exception - you wouldn't get a C level crash. Those are pretty much by definition either a bug in ruby (or an ruby extension) or a problem with how ruby was built on your machine

Comment: Is there a chance to debug what`s going wrong?

Comment: why can't you just add a `:user_id` to attr_accessible in the model? Won't you be creating SomeModel instances with user_id in the code?

Comment: @alony: Because arbitrarily adding attributes to `attr_accessible` defeats the purpose of it. If `user_id` is added (note: you'd actually have to add `user` for his code), then users could add a `user_id` param in their hash and set the association to any user they wanted. Of course, you could prevent that by scoping associations like this: `@user.some_models.create FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:some_model, name: "test name")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, but anyway if you define your factory with the association, it should assign the record even with `attr_protected`

```
factory :some_model do |sm|

  sm.name "John"
  sm.full_name "John Smith"
  sm.other_name  "some other"

  sm.association :user, :factory => :user
end
```

and than

```
describe "test" do
  it "should create models with associations" do
    Factory(:some_model, name: "test name", user: User.first) #factory
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems different from what I got due to attr_accessible.
However, you can simply add **:user** to attr_accessible

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need that in `SomeModel`?

```
belongs_to :user
```