# Factory Girl and Rails with Cucumber gives undefined method error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

I have a Model that looks like this

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

And my factories.rb looks like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    name "testname"
  end
end
```

Then when I call FactoryGirl.create(:course) in Cucumber like so:

```
Given /^there are courses in the database$/ do
    FactoryGirl.create(:course)
end
```

I receive an undefined method error:

```
undefined method `name=' for #<Course id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> (NoMethodError)
```

It all works fine when I use attr_accessor instead of attr_accessible in the Model, but according to other examples I've found it should work with both. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Links to examples where they say it should work:

[How to create factories with attr_accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186425/how-to-create-factories-with-attr-accessible)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/factory_girl/gjLXp96Acyg

https://gist.github.com/334413/2a0f60a9afbff321d3e96727ec17bab53c484128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either should work provided that the fields in question exist in your database. ActiveRecord generates accessors (which FactoryGirl depends on) for attributes specified in `attr_accessible` but only if they are defined in the associated database table.

Comment: Added links to some examples now.

Comment: Ok, this is indeed a little confusing and I'm not sure I have it right. In addition to the references you provided, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700785/using-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible-on-the-same-field.

In short, I believe either should indeed work, provided that there are columns in the associated database table. That is, I believe ActiveRecord will provide the accessors for any database fields that are `attr_accessible`. I'll update my answer, but can you check to see if you've got the database set up properly (e.g. have migrated `name`).

Comment: Ah yes, it seems the database wasn't migrated properly. The `schema.rb` file was lacking the name column, and re-migrating with `rake db:rollback` and `rake db:migrate` fixed it. Thanks a bunch!